# C# ImmutableList как им пользоваться?

Tags: c#

Споткнулся в самом начале, не могу инициализировать список, видимо из-за того что список неизменяемый
Как с ним работать? Как присвоить ему массив?

```
ImmutableList<int> firstList = new ImmutableList<int>();
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dn456080(v=vs.111).aspx

Comment: @HasmikGaryaka я долго читал про него в MSDN, увы не разобрался, кода примера использования по этому классу там нет

Comment: @HasmikGaryaka чтобы использовать методы класса для этой переменной, её нужно инициализировать(выделить для неё память), что у меня и показано на скриншоте

Comment: Если взять массив, который поддерживает IEnumerable, можно и через AddRange

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вот пример создания

```
var builder = ImmutableList.CreateBuilder<string>();
builder.Add("1");  // Adds item to the existing object
ImmutableList<string> list = builder.ToImmutable();
ImmutableList<string> list2 = list.Add("2");  // Creates a new object with 2 items
```

Взято [отсюда](https://habrahabr.ru/post/266873/)

Answer (score 0):

Ещё один вариант:

```
int[] data = {1, 2, 3};
ImmutableList<int> firstList = ImmutableList.CreateRange(data);
```

Answer (score -2):

или так:

```
int[] data = {1, 2, 3};

var firstList = data.ToImmutableList();
```